# Transform CSS rule to custom property the Vim way

Tags: vim

I'd like to edit a CSS file that contains a set of CSS rules with a particular form into CSS custom properties. I'd like to know a good (keystroke efficient) way to do this edit in Vim. I know enough about Vim to get this edit done, but in the interest of mastering Vim, I'd like to see some better methods.

Example:

```
/* two existing rules */
.s-base03 {
    color: #002b36;
 }   
.s-base02 {
    color: #073642;
}

/* replace existing rules with two new custom properties */
--base03: #002b36;
--base02: #073642;
```

I'm assuming there is a search and replace command that would do the trick, but I'm not sure I would know how to account for multiple lines in the regex, and there may just be a better way. Thanks!

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: You'd probably be better using CSS variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are lots of lines like that, the following replace would be fine. If there are only 2 or 3 lines, it wouldn't be as efficient though.

```
:%s/^\.s-\([a-z0-9\-]\+\) {\n\s\+color: \(.\+\);\n}/\--\1: \2;/g
```

Also make sure to format/indent the code first for uniformity. For example, you have an extra space on line 4.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I ended up using:
    :%s/^.s-\(\w\+\)\s\+{\n\s\+color:\s\+\(.\+\)\n}/\--\1: \2/g